# Adding values in a dictionary together

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a program for my college class to add items to a shopping cart and display the total price and quantity. Here is my sample code. Afterwards I will be transferring this information into a Class file:

```
shop_cart = {}


item_quantity = int(input('How many items? '))
print()
for i in range(item_quantity):
    print('Item #', i+1, sep=' ')
    item_name = str(input('Item Name: '))
    item_price = float(input('Item Price: '))
    shop_cart[item_name] = item_price
    item_quantity = int(input('Item Quantity: '))
    shop_cart[item_name] = item_price, item_quantity
    print()
print('Shopping Cart: ', shop_cart)
print()    
remove = str(input('Do you want to remove items? (Y/N): '))
if remove == 'Y':
    remove_item = int(input('How many items to remove? '))
    for i in range(remove_item):
        remove_name = str(input('Enter item name to be removed: '))
        del shop_cart[remove_name]
        print(remove_name, 'has been removed from shopping cart.')

print()
print('Shopping Cart: ', shop_cart)
print('Checking out')
```

I am having trouble multiplying the `item_price` by the `item_quantity` and then adding all the values together to create a "total value" object.

Comment: Please expand on *"having trouble"* with a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the values in your dictionary are tuples, you can get all of them with [`.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) and then use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to add all the products of each tuple:

```
print('Shopping Cart: ', shop_cart)
print('Total: ', sum(price * quantity for price, quantity in shop_cart.values()))
```

**Output**

```
Shopping Cart:  {'Banana': (1.0, 6), 'Apple': (2.0, 5)}                                                                                             
Total:  16.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import starmap
import operator as op
total = sum(starmap(op.mul, cart.values())
```

Comment: This'll work, but could you explain why you think `reduce`, `starmap` and `operator.add` are needed at all here?